# How To do Ajax In Wordpress Custom Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

[image]

I have Php File For Country State City Dropdown in Which I get Particular state list according to partcular country selection and cities list according to particular state selection .Now I Want To Get Same Result Through Wordpress Custom Plugin.How Can I Achieve It means particular states list based on particular country selection in my wordpress custom plugin?

I have tried to create custom plugin in wordpress  like this by referring link-https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-via-ajax-on-change-in-another-dropdown-menu/112739/5 but it not shows states dropdown .I don't know Error,Plz Help.

```
<?php 
/*
 * Plugin Name: ajax Drop
 * Plugin URI: #
 * Description: ajax testing.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Seven Digital Technology
 * Author URI: http://www.sevendigitaltechnology.com
 * License: A "Case Studies" license name e.g. GPL2
 */

//define('ACFSURL', WP_PLUGIN_URL."/".dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );

//efine('ACFPATH', WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/".dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );

function ajaxcontact_enqueuescripts()

{

    wp_localize_script('fetch_state', 'ajaxcontactajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajaxcontact_enqueuescripts);

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'callback_plug' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'remove_plug' );
//callback function
function callback_plug(){
global $wpdb;
$table_country = $wpdb->prefix . "ajacs_drops";
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_country) {
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      entry_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      country_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      state_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    )");
    for($i=0;$i<count($countries);$i++)
    {$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_country(country_name) VALUES('".$countries[$i]."')");}
}
/*$table_state = $wpdb->prefix . "ajacs_state";
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      state_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      country_ID INT NOT NULL,
      state_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL  
    )");
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_country(country_name,state_name) VALUES('1','".$state."')");
}
else
{
}

$table_city = $wpdb->prefix . "ajacs_city";
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      city_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      state_ID INT NOT NULL,
      city_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL  
    )");
}
else
{
}*/
}


function remove_plug()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."ajacs_drops";
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");
}

if(is_admin())
{ 
    add_action('admin_menu', 'client_form_f1');
    function client_form_f1()
    {
        add_menu_page('ajax','ajax Data','administrator','ajacs','client_form_fetch');
        //add_submenu_page('case_studies','Display Clients','Display Clients','manage_options','case_slug','client_one_html_page');

    }
}

function client_form_fetch()
{
    $countries = array("India","america");
    $all = array("India"=>array("Gujarat","Madhya Pradesh","Rajasthan"));   
?>


    <table><tr><td><select name='country' id="country" onchange="state()">
    <option value=''>Select Country</option>"; 
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($countries);$i++)
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $countries[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $countries[$i]; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select> </td><td id='state'></td></tr></table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      //alert('Hii');
    function state(){
    $.ajax
    ({

    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxcontactajax.ajaxurl,

    data: 
    {
        action:'fetch_state()',
        country:$('#country').val(),
    },
    success:function(res)
    {
        $('#state').html(res);
    },

    });}
    </script>
    <?php
    //return $send;
}

function fetch_state()
{
    //global $wpdb;
    //$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."ajacs_state";
    //$sel_state_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE country_ID = '".$_POST['country']."'");

    $send = "<select name='state'>";
    $send .="<option value=''>Select State</option>"; 

    for($i=0;$i<count($all);$i++)
    {
        if($all[i] == $_POST['country'])
        {
        for($j=0;$j<count($all[$i]);$j++)
        {

        $send .= "<option value=".$all[$i][$j].">".$all[$i][$j]."</option>";
        }}
    }

    $send .= "</select> ";


    return $send;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxcontact_send_mail', 'fetch_state' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxcontact_send_mail', 'fetch_state' );
/*function fetch_city()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."ajacs_city";
    $sel_state_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE state_ID = '".$_POST['state']."'");

    $send = "<select name='state' onChange='fetch_city(this.value)'>";
    $send .="<option value=''>Select Country</option>"; 

    foreach($sel_state_data as $sel)
    {

        $send .= "<option value=".$sel->city_ID.">".$sel->city_name."</option>";

    }

    $send .= "</select> ";


    return $send;

}*/


/*function get_city($sid)
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax
    ({

    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxcontactajax.ajaxurl,

    data: 
    {
        action:'fetch_city()',
        country:<?php echo $sid?>,
    },
    success:function(res)
    {
        $('#city').html(res);
    },

    });
    </script>
<?php 
}*/
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead of AJAX? It's a lot easier to get going, WP AJAX has pitfalls

Comment: What had you tried? Which part of implementing Ajax in a plugin you have trouble with specifically?

Comment: You Can Suggest Me Custom Page Template Code In Wordpress For That Also.